# How I can add buttons to the Action Bar?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I want to add buttons to my action bar. How I can do this?

Comment: You mean button literally ?? Or action bar with icons which onclick perform some operations??

Comment: with icons which onclick perform some operations

Answer (score 1):

**You'd better start with some search and if could not find any answer then ask your question!**

By the way:

1. create an android resource file and name it something like `menu_buttons.xml`.
2. Then inflate it and assign to a `View` object in `onCreate` method and use it in your `ActionBar` like:

   ```
   View v = LayoutInflater.from(yourContext).inflate(R.layout.menu_buttons, null);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/ Refer this link... It explains everything from scratch and you have everything you need to know like adding menu items on action bar... handling click events and what code to add where.. So pls go through this